# JavaScript - check if in global context

Tags: javascript, object, global

When a function is attached to an object and called:

```
function f() { return this.x; }
var o = {x: 20};
o.func = f;
o.func(); //evaluates to 20
```

`this` refers to the object that the function was called as a method of. It's equivalent to doing `f.call(o)`.

When the function is called not as part of an object, `this` refers to the global object. How do I check if a function is being called from a non-object context? Is there any standard keyword to access the global object? Is the only way to do it something like this?

```
globalobj = this;
function f() { if (this == globalobj) doSomething(); }
```

Note: I have no particular use case in mind here - I actually am asking about this exact mechanism.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The global object is actually the window so you can do

```
if (this === window)
```

Comment: True at least if the script is running in a browser (since javascript now can be run in other places it might not be a universal truth)

Comment: is this a standard across browsers?

Comment: That depends on the browsers implementation of JavaScript engine, but that is mostly the case.

Comment: It's true for FF, IE, Opera and Chrome on Windows. A little more info: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: "Objects and this", "In a simple function call,  this is set to the Global Object (aka window), which is not very useful.", http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html

Comment: In the same document, "Global object": "In the web browsers, window and self are members of the Global Object which point to the Global Object, thus giving an indirect way of addressing it."

Answer (score 9):

The below should work since using Function.call with a value of null will invoke it in the global scope.

```
this === ((function () { return this; }).call(null))
```

A simpler variant,

```
this === (function () { return this; })()
```

will also work, but I think the first makes the intent clearer.

Comment: The tags do not specify if this is browser only question and this answer works in both node.js and a browser

Answer (score 1):

RoBorg's answer is conceptually correct -- except `window` is only available in the context of the browsers main thread (so this necessarily excludes worker threads and the like, as well as any non-browser hosted JS, which is getting less and less uncommon).

Your safest bet is basically what you had above, but you should use `var` and `===` as it is possible for the interpreter to optimise such accesses more completely.